# Сохранение ArrayList<File> в файл и его чтение

Tags: java, android

Имеется:

```
List<File> mImg = new ArrayList<>();

File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"DIR/");
File[] fileArray = dir.listFiles();
mImg.addAll(Arrays.asList(fileArray));
```

В приложении реализован Drag & Drop, перетаскиваем и меняем местами картинки. После выхода из приложения картинки возвращаются в первоначальное положение. 
Как я понимаю необходимо сохранять строки ArrayList в файл(к примеру txt) перед выходом, а при запуске получать обратно. 
C сохранением проблем нет, а вот обратно заполнить List никак не могу.

Сохраняем:

```
void writeFileSD() {
    if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "SD-карта не доступна: " + Environment.getExternalStorageState());
        return;
    }
    File sdPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    sdPath = new File(sdPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + DIR_SD);
    sdPath.mkdirs();
    File sdFile = new File(sdPath, FILENAME_SD);
    try {
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(sdFile));
        bw.write(mImg.toString());
        bw.close();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Файл записан на SD: " + sdFile.getAbsolutePath()+"text  "+mImg);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Читаем:

```
 void readFileSD() {
    if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "SD-карта не доступна: " + Environment.getExternalStorageState());
        return;
    }
    File sdPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    sdPath = new File(sdPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + DIR_SD);
    File sdFile = new File(sdPath, FILENAME_SD);
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sdFile));
        String data = "";
        while ((data = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Data.add(data);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG,"Читаем  " + data+"Список  "+Data);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Читаем файл и заполняем  `List<String> Data = new ArrayList<String>();` 
строками (пути к файлам). В адаптер необходимо передать сами файлы `List<File>. Как преобразовать?`

Comment: Сущетвуют потоки для записи объектов вроде. ObjectInput/OutputStream

Comment: Вам достаточно сохранить просто пути к файлам, которые содержатся в `List<File> mImg`, а потом просто загрузить эти пути, создать по ним объекты `File` и добавить их в `ArrayList`.